# Where should I resize the vector in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have a very simple question: when we use the vector `std::vector<int>` as the reference parameter of a function, should we resize the vector before calling the function or resizing the vector inside the function (suppose the size of the vector can be determined before hand? I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
void fun1(std::vector<int> &para)
{
  para[0] = 1;
  para[1] = 2;
  ....
  para[10] = 11;

}
void fun2(std::vector<int> &para)
{
  para.resize(11);
  para[0] = 1;
  para[1] = 2;
  ...
  para[10] = 11;
}
```

When we invoke fun1, we are using the following codes:

```
std::vector<int> mypara;
mypara.resize(11);
fun1(mypara);
```

When we invoke fun2, we are using the following codes:

```
std::vector<int> mypara;
fun2(mypara);
```

Comment: I'd say always in the function...the end user has no way of knowing that fun1 requires an 11 long vector (unless they read your comments), and the overhead of resizing to the same or smaller vector is pretty small. As a general rule of thumb for programming: the person that will have to maintain your code is an idiot. This is especially true if you have to maintain your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not normally explicitly `resize` a vector at all -- neither in the function call nor before you call the function.  `vector` manages its own memory usage, and grows as needed to accommodate new elements.

There are circumstances where you will be adding mane elements and do not want to suffer numerous re-allocations of the vector for performance reasons.  This will normally occur only in the "hot path" of you application, and not for every application.  In these relatively rare scenarios, the function that adds elements should be responsible for enusring there is enough capacity in the vector.  To do this, you do not use `resize`, but `reserve`.  Both will reallocate the `vector` if necesarry (and consequently invalidate iterators, so beware), but `resize` actually changes botht the `size()` and `capacity()` of the `vector`, whereas `reserve` only changes the `capacity()`.

To understand the difference:

```
vector <int> v;
v.reserve (10);
copy (v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator (cout, ","));
```

The above will output nothing because there is nothing "in" the `vector`, even though there is room for 10 elements.  However:

```
vector <int> v;
v.resize (10);
copy (v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator (cout, ","));
```

This code will output 10 default-constructed `int`s.  There are 10 elements in the array.  If you are `resizing()` a `vector` simply to make room for new elements, `resize()` probably isn't what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Just use push_back and let the vector do the resizing itself when it is necessary:

```
std::vector<int> mypara;
mypara.push_back(1);
...
mypara.push_back(11);
```

If you know how many elements will fit in your vector you can call `reserve` before adding the elements or set the initial size as parameter:

```
std::vector<int> mypara(10);//Be aware that this will create 10 elements!
//or...
std::vector<int> mypara;
mypara.reserve(10);//This will set the size, but there won't be any elements in it yet.
```

The initial size of the vector is big enough for most cases and it won't resize very often. But sometimes it can lead to a problem when you add only one element and it gets resized to a way bigger size. In this case using reserve can improve performance too.

But if you have to do a resizing, do it in the function in your case. It's clearer to the reader of the code and it can be seen what you're intending. Keep the scope small.

Comment: I also agree with using `push_back` instead of indexing into the vector. However, depending on the real number of items it may be interesting to call `reserve` (not `resize` mind you) beforehand.

Comment: Beware that this approach can bite. For example, when you already have 1024 elements and need just one more,  the vector may as well resize to 2048 and waste memory worth 1023 elements.

Answer (score 3):

...You probably should just return the vector.

```
std::vector<int> fun3()
{
  std::vector<int> para(11);
  para[0] = 1;
  para[1] = 2;
  ...
  para[10] = 11;
  return para;
}
```

I know this feels wrong, but C++/the STL is actually super smart about this sort of thing. It won't actually copy out para, it will do a move constructor/do return value optomization rather than a copy constructor.

http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: What is most likely to happen is return value optimization, which works pre-C++11 and doesn't require move constructors in C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza oh that's nifty, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, though fun2 seems be a bit safer. You can copy it to another project and it would work just fine as opposed to fun1 that requires para to be sized correclty beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If your function has requirements on the input vector, does not use its data, and assumes that it is overwriteable, then it may be better to simply return the vector by value:

```
std::vector<int> fun()
{
  std::vector<int> v(11);
  std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
  return v;
}
```

This way, the caller doesn't have to worry about what the state of an input vector must be, and the function doesn't have to do any checking on the vector.

Answer (score 1):

i think if u can know at run time what would be the size you require now , you should call resize . Why ? as this will prevent the overhead of multiple time of size increase and copying ...

So answer is .. at the moment in your function when  you know that a large chunk of insertion are going to happen , so you would like to do it at once ...